# Django Hostname in Testing

Tags: python, django, hostname

I am wondering if there is a way to obtain the hostname of a Django application when running tests. That is, I would like the tests to pass both locally and when run at the staging server. Hence a need to know `http://localhost:<port>` vs. `http://staging.example.com` is needed because some tests query particular URLs.

I found answers on how to do it inside templates, but that does not help since there is no `response` object to check the hostname.

How can one find out the hostname outside the views/templates? Is it stored in Django settings somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried setting environment variables?

Comment: I do set environment variables. But that is not something I want to set in environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to know the hostname? Tests can run just fine without it, if you use the test client. You do not need to know anything about the system they're running on.

You can also mark tests with a tag and then have the CI system run the tests including that tag.

And finally there is the [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase):

> LiveServerTestCase does basically the same as TransactionTestCase with one extra feature: it launches a live Django server in the background on setup, and shuts it down on teardown. This allows the use of automated test clients other than the Django dummy client such as, for example, the Selenium client, to execute a series of functional tests inside a browser and simulate a real user’s actions.
>
> The live server listens on localhost and binds to port 0 which uses a free port assigned by the operating system. The server’s URL can be accessed with `self.live_server_url` during the tests.

Additional information from comments:

- You can test if the URL of an image file is present in your response by testing for the MEDIA_URL:
  `self.assertContains(response, f'{settings.MEDIA_URL}/default-avatar.svg')`
- You can test for the existence of an upload in various ways, but the easiest one is to check if there's a file object associated with the [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile). It will throw `ValueError` if there is not.

Comment: I need to know it because depending on the environment, the URLs will either be short and local or CDN-like.`MEDIA_URL = "/media/"` vs `MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `settings.MEDIA_URL` will always be correct, so write your tests as `self.assertContains(response, f'{settings.MEDIA_URL}/default-avatar.svg')`.

Comment: Does that test for existence of that file? That is what my goal is.